# request for member “…” in “…” which is of non-class type “…”

Tags: c++, class, dictionary

In my c++ program I have my own custom map composed of custom Nodes in which I am trying to obtain the "first" and "second" values (like std::map). I tried many different syntax's but to no avail.

I know the usual fix for this problem is replacing `(*key_Iterator).first` with `(*key_Iterator)->first` but in this case I need to be able to access the values in the first method.

I added the variables in the iterator class but the program did not recognize them.

```
template <class T, class P>
class Iterator {
  public:
    Node<T,P>* operator*() { return ptr_; }
  private:
    Node<T,P>* ptr_;
    T first;
    P second;
}
```

Any advice on how to properly implement the first version and removing this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Uh, you return a pointer from `operator *`, so of course you will have to use `->` syntax on the return value...

Comment: (Also, it's not clear at all what you are actually asking. "access the values in the first method"? What "first method"? What values?)

Comment: I naturally find that -> syntax makes more sense. But with this program guidelines required I extract the first value using (*itr).first and I do not know why that syntax will not work.

Comment: Try returning a reference from `operator *`: `Node<T,P> &operator *() { return *ptr_; }`

Comment: @nneonneo: Thank you, I tried your suggestion and that appears to have worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Moving from comment)

The solution is to return a *reference* from your `operator *`, like so:

```
Node<T,P> &operator *() { return *ptr_; }
```